# Is there any significant advantage that UniswapV3 has over UniswapV2 in a Flashloan(or Flashswap) scenario?

Tags: solidity, uniswapv3, flash-loans, flashbots, uniswapv2

I have been following the flash loan market for a while and I want to eventually experiment on it but i am having a hard time choosing between UniswapV2 and uniswapV3 for making my swaps. Is there any advantage that one has over the other in respect to flashswaps ?

Usings Aave as borrower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should really use both, imo. The more DEXes your bot is compatible with, the more profit opportunities you get.

To answer your question though, basically the only thing you'd care about in your situation is that v3 costs more gas to use but due to its concentrated liquidity thingy, you're more likely to have your swaps have a smaller price impact if you're swapping large amounts (which would be the case with a flashloan, obviously) depending on how the liquidity is distributed

---

Edit to answer the comment : Not really. Both swaps are going to be "sucessful" in the way that the transaction will complete in both cases no matter the amount of initial liquidity, but the amount you get out of it will be different. Let's imagine we're swapping USDT for ETH

- Uniswap v2 uses the constant product formula to determine the output amount, meaning the product of both reserves is always the same number

```
x * y = k
```

Where x is the reserve of token0 (USDT), y the reserve of token1 (ETH) and k a constant that must be maintainted. When selling 1M USDT for ETH, we get

```
(x + a) * (y - b) = k
```

Where a is the amount of USDT sold, and b is the amount of ETH received from that sale. Let's assume that x = 1M and y = 5000 (the initial price of 1 ETH is 200 USDT). Naively, when swapping 1M USDT you'd expect to get 5000 eth, but no, let's plug the numbers in our formula

```
// Initial liq + amount swapped
     ( 1 000 000 + 1 000 000 ) * (5000 - b) = k
```

Where k is

```
1 000 000 * 5 000 = 5 000 000 000
```

So

```
5000 - b = 5 000 000 000 / 2 000 000 = 2500
```

Therefore

```
b = 5000 - 2500 = 2500
```

We only got 2500 ETH (and the new reserves are 2M usdt and 2500 ETH, k is by definition still 5 billion and the new price is 2M/2500 = 800 USDT/ETH)

- For v3, things get *much* more complicated as liquidity is concentrated, and we can't derive a general formula as it depends on *how* exactly it is concentrated, but the general idea is that liquidity providers set a range in there where liquidity is active. In practice, that means more liquidity around the current price, and less and less liquidity the further away we drift from the current price. If you make a swap that is comparatively small compared to the total liquidity in the pair, you will get more ETH

Comment: Alright, this is helpful. That means swapping $1M(for example) has a higher chances of being successful in v3 than in v2 right ? If understand you well.

Comment: Answered in an edit @ShigabaShigaba

Comment: I understand now, thank you.